# Write $7 \cdot 10^{100} + 7$ as a sum of four squares

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, sums-of-squares, sum-of-squares-method

How do you write $7 \cdot 10^{100} +7$ as a sum of four squares?

I know that you can write it as a sum of four squares by the Lagrange's Four Squares Theorem, but I don't know how to write such a big number as a sum of four squares. I've tried writing $10^{100}$ as ${(10^{50})}^2$ or as $10^{10} \cdot 10^{10} \cdot 10^{10} \cdot 10^{10} \cdot 10^{10} \cdot 10^{10} \cdot 10^{10} \cdot 10^{10} \cdot 10^{10} \cdot 10^{10} \cdot$ and then work it out but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Write $7$ and  $10^{100}+1$ as sum of 4 squares and apply [Euler 4-square identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity).

Comment: How do you write though $10^{100} + 1$ as the sum of four squares?

Comment: $10^{100} + 1 = (10^{50})^2 + 1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2$

Comment: But then how do you combine them? I'm going to multiply $2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2$ which is $7$ by $(10^{50})^2 + 1^2 + 0^2 +0^2$? If so how I'm going to write the final answer?

Comment: Apply the Euler's four-square identity. See the link given by achille hui

Comment: Is the final answer supposed to be $(2 \cdot 10^{50} -1)^2 +(2+10^{50})^2 + (10^{50}+1)^2 + (-1+10^{50})^2$ ?

Comment: @user1052623 Yes, this a representation of $10^{100} + 1$ as a sum of four squares